# html_entity_decode not having any effect

Tags: php, html-entities

I've read other questions here but none of the answers seems to fix this issue

my MySQL query brings back `"Dino&#39;s"`

```
$var = Dino& # 39; s; (no spaces);
```

I need to convert that `'&#39;'` (no spaces) to `"'"`  a single quote/apostrophe

I have tried the following and none seems to work.

```
$var = html_entity_decode( $var, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8' );
$var = html_entity_decode( $var, ENT_COMPAT, 'ISO-8859-1' );
$var = html_entity_decode( $var );
```

Only when I add this line will the remainder of my script work.

```
$var = str_replace( '&#39;', "'", $var );
```

Obviously I may need to to function for other html_entities so I need a solution other than that just above.

What am I overlooking, please?

Comment: `html_entity_decode('&#39;')` works for me.  Have you confirmed the source character set?  Can you `var_dump` the input string and check there aren't any extra bytes in there?

Comment: Thanks Rob. $var = html_entity_decode($var, ENT_QUOTES); did it for me.

Answer (score 2):

Use at least *ENT_QUOTES* or similar instead of *ENT_COMPAT*.
As your goal is to convert the (single)-quotes from the html_entity back to character-representation. *ENT_COMPAT* won't convert single-quotes.

[onlinephp.io Demonstration](https://onlinephp.io?s=s7EvyCjg5dLXV3DNK0ktUqjMLy1SSM5PSVXISC1K1VFIzcvKr1Tk5VIpSyxSsFVQd8nMy1dTNra0Lla35uVKTc7IV1ACy8XkKQEFgApBJoSlFhVn5ucBNWSU5ObEp-aVZJZUxqekggzWACnXUXD1C4l39vcNcAzRhOjLrSRSV2Cof4hrMEQX1AFIdirBnRWDxEaYrmQNAA%2C%2C&v=8.2.13)

From [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php):

| Constant Name | Description |
| --- | --- |
| ENT_COMPAT | Will convert double-quotes and leave single-quotes alone. |
| ENT_QUOTES | Will convert both double and single quotes. |
| ENT_NOQUOTES | Will leave both double and single quotes unconverted. |
| ENT_SUBSTITUTE | Replace invalid code unit sequences with a Unicode Replacement Character U+FFFD (UTF-8) or � (otherwise) instead of returning an empty string. |
| ENT_HTML401 | Handle code as HTML 4.01. |
| ENT_XML1 | Handle code as XML 1. |
| ENT_XHTML | Handle code as XHTML. |
| ENT_HTML5 | Handle code as HTML 5. |

Comment: Thank you very much A.copter.  Working as expected now. Thanks for that very useful resource too.